# Free stuff -  "swag" or "schwag"?

Tags: orthography

My company gives out free promotional items with the company name on it.  Is this stuff called company *swag* or *schwag*?

It seems that both come up as common usages—Google searching indicates that the bias is slightly towards *swag*.  Can anybody provide any definite proof of the root of the word and which one is more correct?

Comment: Why the -1?  At least make a comment explaining...

Comment: It's called *swag* on Stack Exchange, see e.g. http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/english-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users

Comment: It's "swag". "Schwag" is just how pirates said "swag" in the old movies.

Comment: I've never heard the term *swag* in this context. Is it an Americanism? I think *freebies* may be more common in the UK?

Comment: Swag is stuff we all get, schwag is cheap, crappy, brown marijuana

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is called *swag*, which some people believe stands for "Stuff We All Get" (the more PG version of the two variations).

Another relevant expansion is "Souvenirs, Wearables and Gifts" ([ref](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Stuff+We+All+Get))

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swag) defines *swag* as

> 2.Handouts, freebies, or giveaways, such as those handed out at conventions.

It seems that in written English, *swag* is the way to go:

[image: Swag v shwag v schwag Google ngram showing swag leading by far]

Perhaps the most definitive answer stems from an entry in Francis Grose's [Classical Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue](http://books.google.com/books?id=bJc-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PT215&dq=%22swag%22&hl=en&ei=v66oTqbLBYWz0QGbs9T6DQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CEYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22swag%22&f=false)(1823), with a couple definitions for "swag" including:

> SWAG. A bundle, parcel, or package ; as a *swag* of *snow, &c. The swag*, is a term used in speaking of any booty you have lately obtained, be it of what kind it may, except money ; as where did you *lumber the swag?* that is, where did you deposit the stolen property? [...]

Comment: I didn't know that, but I bet it was called 'swag' first by analogy with a burglar's haul, and only later did someone make an acronym of it.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schwag 2. (slang) cheap giveaway promotional items.  I like your answer, but it looks like the general population uses both.  I'm curious if one is historical or more correct.  I do like "Stuff We All Get" though - sounds like that could be the origin of the term.  Perhaps Schwag is just an alteration of that?

Comment: It's quite possible.

Comment: SWAG, meaning "Stuff we all get," is an example of a *backronym*. The word existed first and then was misapplied to give-away stuff. The letters of a real word were then used to create an acronym. In short, the word existed, and then the acronym was created from the letters in the word. Backronyms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backronym

Comment: @BarrieEngland Looks like you were right. The reference I've just added is from a "classical dictionary of the vulgar tongue" from 1823, and intimates that that is the case.

Answer (score 5):

Both are correct, but *swag* is the earlier word, and the one I would use. It was used for promotional items in 2001.  Before this new meaning, I knew it to mean the stuff a thief has stolen (often hauled in a swag bag in cartoons). From [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=swag):

> The noun sense of "ornamental festoon" is first found 1794. Colloquial sense of "promotional material" (from recording companies, etc.) was in use by 2001; swag was English criminal's slang for "quantity of stolen property, loot" from c.1839. Earlier senses of "bulky bag" (c.1300) and "big, blustering fellow" (1580s) may represent separate borrowings from the Scandinavian source.

Stuff We All Get is a later "backronym".

The first *schwag* as promo stuff I heard was stickers and so on given out by Flickr mid last decade, as their fun variation of *swag*.

(See also [here](http://www.hellocomein.com/hellowords/2008/03/12/word-usage-of-swag-vs-schwag/) for schwag as low grade marijuana, possibly from Yiddish.)

**Edit:** promotional swag dates back to at least 1961, and promotional schwag to at least 2001: ["Of course, one must never underestimate the influence of Wayne’s World [1988-1994] and schwing."](http://nancyfriedman.typepad.com/away_with_words/2011/09/swag-and-schwag.html)

Comment: I had never heard of a swag bag until you mentioned it here.  Then I saw it in a web comic today: http://www.explosm.net/comics/3196/